# Bold Part of TextBox/RichTextBox in C# Code

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, textbox

There are many examples of how to format the text in a TextBox via xaml code, but I am trying to figure out how to change the code in my .cs file.

```
//TextBox tb initialized in .xaml code
tb.Text = "<bold>Bold</bold> and normal and <italic>Italic</italic>";
```

is along the lines of what I am looking for.  Is this possible?

The end result would look like:

**Bold** and normal and *Italic*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that for **`RichTextBox`** by adding Inlines like this:

```
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run("Bold")));
paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run(" and normal"));
paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Italic(new Run(" and Italic")));
richTextBox.Document = new FlowDocument(paragraph);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to use `TextBlock` you can use the following:

```
this.myTextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run("Bold")));
this.myTextBlock.Inlines.Add(" and normal and ");
this.myTextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Italic(new Run("italic")));
```

Otherwise, if you have to use `TextBox` you can only apply style to whole text, for example using `myTextBox.FontWeight`.